# align text in math mode

Tags: math-mode, equations

I have the following equation (I use MathType and then exctract it in LaTeX):

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
{{\textrm{Dot product:}}}&{{\rm{            }}{\sigma _{ij}}{n_j} \Leftrightarrow {\bf{\sigma n}}}
\end{array}}\\
{\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\textrm{Double dot product:}}}&{\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{L_{ijkl}}{\varepsilon _{kl}} = {\bf{L\varepsilon }}\\
{L_{ijkl}}{T_{klpq}} = {\bf{LT}}
\end{array} \right.}
\end{array}}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

which produces

[image]

How is it possible to align the text in the left?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MathType is not really doing a good work: it's much simpler to type in LaTeX directly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&\text{Dot product:}        &\quad& \sigma_{ij}{n_j} = \sigma\mathbf{n} \\
&\text{Double dot product:} &\quad&
  \begin{cases}
  L_{ijkl}\varepsilon_{kl} = \mathbf{L}\varepsilon \\
  L_{ijkl}T_{klpq} = \mathbf{L}\mathbf{T}
  \end{cases}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This answer is similar to the one by Enrico, but is using `aligned` instead of `alignedat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    & \textrm{Dot product:} && \sigma_{ij} n_j \Leftrightarrow \mathbf{\sigma n} \\
    & \textrm{Double dot product:} &&
    \begin{cases}
      L_{ijkl} \varepsilon_{kl} = \mathbf{L\varepsilon} \\
      L_{ijkl} T_{klpq} = \mathbf{LT}
    \end{cases}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I guess I will receive many answers. Indeed MathType does not do do a good job at all! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much simpler code with `alignedat` and `cases` environments. Use the `bm` package to have bold Greek letters.You don't need all those pairs of `{ }`. Also note font commands such as `\rm,`\bf`, &c. shouldn't be used as they're plain TeX commands, and they don't work well w.r.t. New Font Selection Scheme (N.F.S.S.) which has been new for more than 20 years…

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    & \textrm{Dot product:}&&\quad\sigma _{ij}n_j\Leftrightarrow \bm{\sigma}\mathbf{n}\\
    & \textrm{Double dot product:} &\enspaAce & \begin{cases}
    L_{ijkl}\varepsilon _{kl} = \mathbf{L}\bm{\varepsilon }\\
    L_{ijkl}T_{klpq} = \mathbf{LT}
    \end{cases}
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you include `amssymb` and `amsfonts`?  As far as I can see you do not use their functionality in the example.

Comment: @Henry Lenke: You're right. I simply use the preamble of an answer to a previous question. Actually, in a first version of my answer, I used `boldsymbol` instead of `\bm` to bolden Greek letters. Thanks for pointing the confusing preamble.